# Setting the hidden state for each minibatch with different hidden sizes and multiple LSTM layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I created an LSTM using Keras with TensorFlow as backend. Before a minibatch with a num_step of 96 is given to the training, the hidden state of the LSTM is set to true values of a previous time step.

First the parameters and data:

```
batch_size = 10
num_steps = 96
num_input = num_output = 2
hidden_size = 8
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1, num_steps, num_input)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train).reshape(-1, num_steps, num_output)
X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1, num_steps, num_input)
Y_test = np.array(Y_test).reshape(-1, num_steps, num_output)
```

The Keras model consists of two LSTM layers and one layer to trim the output to num_output which is 2:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, batch_input_shape=((batch_size, num_steps, num_input)),
               return_sequences=True, stateful = True)))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(num_output, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The generator, as well as the training (hidden_states[x] has shape (2,)):

```
def gen_data():
        x = np.zeros((batch_size, num_steps, num_input))
        y = np.zeros((batch_size, num_steps, num_output))
        while True:
            for i in range(batch_size):
                model.layers[0].states[0] = K.variable(value=hidden_states[gen_data.current_idx]) # hidden_states[x] has shape (2,)
                x[i, :, :] = X_train[gen_data.current_idx]
                y[i, :, :] = Y_train[gen_data.current_idx]
                gen_data.current_idx += 1
            yield x, y
gen_data.current_idx = 0


for epoch in range(100):
    model.fit_generator(generate_data(), len(X_train)//batch_size, 1,
                        validation_data=None, max_queue_size=1, shuffle=False)
    gen_data.current_idx = 0
```

This code does not give me an error, but I have two questions about it:

1) Inside the generator I set the hidden state of the LSTM `model.layers[0].states[0]` to a variable on `hidden_states[gen_data.current_idx]` with the shape (2,). 
Why is this possible for an LSTM with a hidden size greater than 2?

2) The values in `hidden_states[gen_data.current_idx]` could also be an output from the Keras model. Does it make sense for a two-layer LSTM to set the hidden state in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## States in LSTM

An LSTM is made up of gates which calculate the `cell state` and `hidden state`.
[image]

In the figure the top arrow coming out of the right of LSTM is the cell state (`c_t`) and the bottom arrow is the hidden state (`h_t`). The cell states are the result of gated manipulation and the size of state is same as the `hidden_size` of the LSTM.  Every unrolling (with its corresponding input X) results in its own cell state. In case of LSTM, the cell state is composed of two value hidden_state(`h_t`) of (batch_size x hidden_size) and cell_state (`c_t`) of (batch_size x hidden_size).

```
batch_size = 2
num_steps = 5
num_input = num_output = 1
hidden_size = 8

inputs = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,num_steps, num_input))
lstm, state_h, state_c = LSTM(hidden_size, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[state_h, state_c])

print (model.predict(np.zeros((batch_size, num_steps, num_input))))
print (model.layers[1].cell.state_size)
```

**Note:** In case of GRU/RNN there is no cell state there is only hidden state so the cell state in case is just `h_t` of size (batch_size , hidden_size)

### Reference:

Keras implementation of [LSTM](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1955)

[Keras Docs:](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)

> the number of state tensors is 1 (for RNN and GRU) or 2 (for LSTM).

[Illustrated Guide to LSTM and GRU](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-guide-to-lstms-and-gru-s-a-step-by-step-explanation-44e9eb85bf21)

### Feeding states

In your example the `layers[0]` refers 1 LSTM and `layers[1]` refer to the 2nd LSTM. If your intension is to initialise the cell state (`c_t`) of the nth batch as from the cell state of of (n-1) i.e previous batch there are two options

- The way you are doing in the generator but use `states[1]` if you want `c_t` and  `states[0]` for `h_t`. Similarly use `layers[0]` for 1st LSTM and `layers[1]` for second LSTM. But use `set_value` methods instead. See edit below.
- Use keras `Stateful=True` : With stateful set to true the LSTM states are not reset after every batch. So If you have a batch with 5 data samples (each of some sequence length) you will get a cell state for each of the 5 data samples. With stateful set to true these states are used to initialized the next batch cell state for the next batch.

### Edit:

The method `set_value` should be used to set the value of a tensor variable. The code `model.layers[0].states[0] = K.variable(value=hidden_states[gen_data.current_idx])` is valid because what it is doing is changing the state[0] which was pointing to a variable of size (batch_size X hidden_size) to a a variable of size (batch_size x 2). It is not changing the value of the tensor variable but rather making it point to a new tensor variable of different dimension.

**Test Code:**

```
 print (model.layers[0].states[0], hex(id(model.layers[0].states[0])))
 model.layers[0].states[0]= K.variable(np.random.randn(10,2))
 print (model.layers[0].states[0], hex(id(model.layers[0].states[0])))
```

Output

```
<tf.Variable 'lstm_18/Variable:0' shape=(10, 8) dtype=float32_ref> 0x7f8812e6ee10
<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(10, 2) dtype=float32_ref> 0x7f881269afd0
```

As you can see they are two different variable. The correct way to do this is

```
 print (model.layers[0].states[0], hex(id(model.layers[0].states[0])))
 K.set_value(model.layers[0].states[0], np.random.randn(10,8))
 print (model.layers[0].states[0], hex(id(model.layers[0].states[0])))
```

Output

```
<tf.Variable 'lstm_20/Variable:0' shape=(10, 8) dtype=float32_ref> 0x7f881138eb70
<tf.Variable 'lstm_20/Variable:0' shape=(10, 8) dtype=float32_ref> 0x7f881138eb70
```

If your code is fixed then

```
K.set_value(model.layers[0].states[0], np.random.randn(10,2))
```

Will throw an error as the size of tensor and the size of the value you are setting to do not match.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can't see an answer to my questions. My questions were related to the hidden state `h_t`. My first question was, why is it possible to set `h_t` in my example with  (batch_size x 2) when it normally needs input of shape (batch_size x hidden_size)?

Comment: @MerklT you should be using set_value method to set the value of a tensor. Please check the edited for details.